# Ajax Post Data {post: '[["test",null,null,null,"test"]]'}, why this request return 406

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
POST Data > {post: '[["test",null,null,null,"test"]]'}
RETURN_CODE > 406
RETURN_MESSAGE > Not Acceptable! An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server.
```

This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Full Code:

```
var xtest = [["test", null, null, null, "test"]];
var xtest1 = JSON.stringify(xtest);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {post: xtest1},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Is that a bug or my code is wrong?

Note:
- Working normal on my local
- Show 406 on Hosting

Comment: Because mod_security is notorious for throwing false positives. (I imagine its log files will tell you what rule you are violating).

Comment: Whenever you get an error from a server, we need to see the code/configuration of the server in addition to how you are calling it. In this case how your hosting service configures mod_security, and how that configuration differs from your local configuration, would be key information.

Comment: Ok lets say's there is a different configuration on my **local** mod_security and **hosting** mod_security, but why its return great if i change **var xtest = [["test", null, null, null, "test"]];** to **var xtest = [["test", null, null, "test"]];**. There is just different one **null**. I think its just post data, not related to mod_security. I am sorry if i wrong. Anyway i dont know what is mod_security for now.